# Rails month_field datatypes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, types

I have define date datatypes for my month field in migration file

```
t.date :month
```

And check its valuation in model

```
validates :month, presence: true
```

And in my form,

```
= f.month_field :month, class: "form-control"
```

But while I want to save the data in its not saving. As I debug for my controller

```
params[:rent]
=> {"item"=>"Room", "charge"=>"100", "payment_date(1i)"=>"2014", "payment_date(2i)"=>"12", "payment_date(3i)"=>"11", "month"=>"2014-11"}
```

Check out the month field. We have value over there but when I try to create new record

```
@rent = current_user.rents.new(rent_params)
=> #<Rent id: nil, item: "Room", charge: 100, payment_date: "2014-12-11 00:00:00", month: nil, user_id: 1, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

month field is nil. Why is this ??

My controller code is

```
 def paid
    @rent = current_user.rents.new(rent_params)
    if @rent.save 
      redirect_to payment_url(@rent)
    else
      render "pay"
    end
  end

  private

  def rent_params
    params.require(:rent).permit(:item, :charge, :payment_date, :month)
  end
```

Am I wrong Somewhere ??

Comment: The attribute's date type is date and value from form can't be parsed into it. `Date.parse('2014-11')` raises an error, that's why you get nil

Comment: ohh, what should I do ? Should I change it datetime datatypes ?

Answer (score 0):

amenzhinsky is right, but to expand on a solution:

If you only care about the number of the month, in your migration change:

```
t.date, :month
```

to

```
t.integer, :month
```

And then use [select_month](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.1.8/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/select_month) in your form.

or you can do it manually

select_tag('name', options_for_select([['January', 1], ['February', 2],...]))